# UTF-8 weird behaviour between HTML/PHP forms and MySQL (Hindi)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, hindi

I have all my database/tables and columns set to `UTF-8_general_ci` collation set.

Conditions that I Faced :-

1. When I insert hindi data manually by phpmyadmin, I can see the the hindi characters in phpmyadmin, while question marks when seen on webpage generated by PHP
2. In the same table when I insert data by HTML/PHP Forms I see some unrecognizable words in english something like `cc2faa;`(something like this) and Correct Hindi on Webpage.
3. For the large data we have a script that reads from txt files and insert the data in the table in this , I see characters like `à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¤¾` in phpmyadmin but `Hindi` On webpage.

Now the main problem is :-

Data has gone under changes online by forms and now I need this data to export to excel and give to the client but I am getting `à¤œà¤¾à¤` in excel instead of Hindi Characters.

**Note :-**

- All English characters are working fine and as it is everywhere.
- My  CHARACTER SET is `utf8` For all tables.
- I tried to change the collation to UTF-8_bin but that too doesn't helped me in anyway.
- Encoding on the browser is UTF-8, and I have already sent the headers for UTF-8 encoding.

I have seen many posts about utf8 problem but no one seem to have this weird different behavior problem.

Please Do I have any rescue from this?? Or finally have to give the PHP reports of the data??

Please help!!

Comment: see: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Isn't there is any way when I connect the excel sheet to the database I get Hindi characters instead of those unreadable character??

Comment: Try to run the following query before your select statement, "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. When I insert hindi data manually by phpmyadmin, I can see the the hindi characters in phpmyadmin, while question marks when seen on webpage generated by PHP

PHP probably generates the question marks because the encoding of the *database connection* is not utf-8. How to fix this depends on the database library you use; if you use MySQLi use `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`, if PDO you add `charset=utf8` to the DSN...

> 1. In the same table when I insert data by HTML/PHP Forms I see some unrecognizable words in english something like cc2faa;(something like this) and Correct Hindi on Webpage.
> 2. For the large data we have a script that reads from txt files and insert the data in the table in this , I see characters like à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¤¾ in phpmyadmin but Hindi On webpage.

These are likely caused by the same problem as above: the PHP forms and the script connect to the database using the default encoding, probably latin1. Then they insert utf-8 encoded text, but since MySQL thinks you are using latin1, it encodes the text into utf-8 again, and inserts this doubly encoded text into the table.

So: PHP sends "जाना" to MySQL telling it's latin1, and MySQL goes and converts it to utf-8, resulting in "à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¤¾". Later PHP asks MySQL return the value, and since the connection is again using latin1, MySQL takes "à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¤¾" and decodes it to latin1. Then PHP pretends that this latin1 string is actually utf-8 and displays "जाना".

Again, the solution is setting the encoding of the connection to utf-8. And this depends on what you use to access the database.

Comment: Thumbs Up, Why I haven't thought of that.. Now I understand, thanks a lot :) , you are right I corrected it now I just need to export and reimport the data once and adds up the charset to the connection string :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to export your data as Excel file, use the PHP class `php-export-data` by Eli Dickinson, http://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data. It is pretty nifty and so far I had have no problems exporting weird character sets with it.

Comment: Yes It helps me, Thank you.
But For this I have to write different codes for different tables. Also Using this will not help me in connecting the excel to Database server.